# ISPConfig 3 - Create a new Web site

Tags: linux, web, vps

I have the ISPConfig on the VPS server. (Version 3)

I have three domains: For example: Domain1.com, Domain2.com, Domain3.com
I created a new web site using ISPConfig. (For domain1.com)

When i show the domain - domain1.com - The content is correctly.

When i show the domains - domain2.com and domain3.com The content domains is identical with the domain1.com.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried putting each of the separate domains under different clients?

Comment: I only set the new website for the domain1.com. Automatically displays the contents of my other domains (domain2 and domain3). Why?

Comment: Did you put the content on domain1 via FTP, or is it the default page?  I think [this HowToForge thread](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=32443) will help you.  The way I have mine set up is each domain under different clients -- I've never had any overlapping content issues.  Check out that forum post and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After my IP-Address changed (it's dynamic), I ended up having the same situation as you described.

Here's the solution:

1. In ISPConfig3, click on the Sites tab.  Under the Websites section,
   click on one of the sites displayed, such as domain1.com.
2. Set the `IP-Address` to `*`.
3. Save and repeat this for each of your other websites, domain2, and
   domain3.

[image: ISPConfig > Sites > Website]

You should now be able to access each of your sites, domain1.com, domain2.com, and domain3.com and each of them will display their own content.

Additionally, the default page, located at `http://yourServerIPAddress:80`, will display it's own `index.html` page, which is found in `/var/www`.

Comment: what should the dns settings be?

Comment: I was baffled why ssl kept going to the wrong site - thanks for the help.